# XSD feed to XHTML markup?

Tags: xml, xhtml, xsd

I have a feed here http://artistdata.sonicbids.com/my-lady-four/shows/xml/past that I would like to convert to XHTML. I am very familiar with XHTML, just not really sure how to parse the feed. Is there a jQuery solution or something fairly easy to implement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a XSLT task mostly.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it e.g. with an XSLT processor in PHP.

Here you go: http://www.php.net/manual/de/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php

It's quite simple. Follow the example 1.

I suggest you are not familiar with XSL too? Then I recommend to you this learning website: http://w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp

If you like this approach, let us know, then we can help you writing a transformation (xsl).

Comment: I think I have it working using the demo markup. Is there a way to run htmlspecialchars() on the xml? If there's a "&" and not "&amp" it will break.

Comment: You can basically use PHP functions in XSLT. You have to register PHP functions in your declaration of the XSLT processor (example 1 from the mentioned example): http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php - Afterwards, you have to declare in your XSL-File the Namespace of PHP and use the PHP-function in your select attribute, e.g. <xsl:value-of select="php:htmlspecialchars(@value)"/>. - Check the example in the link to the documentation.